# Подсчет суммы и последующее подставление в условие при выводе записей

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть запрос на вывод авторов, в порядке убывания по значению суммы статистики со всех его публикаций и за последние 30 дней.
**Вот данный код:**

```
$sql_popular = mysql_query("
SELECT `id`,`name`,`view`,`avatar`, 
   ((SELECT SUM((((`like` * 10) + `view`) - (`dizlike` * 10))) 
       FROM `fanfik` 
       WHERE `active`='1' AND `id_users` = `u`.id) + `view`) AS sum_fanfik 
FROM `users` u 
WHERE `activation`='1' AND `date` >= adddate(now(), interval - 30 day) 
ORDER BY sum_fanfik DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 20");
```

Как сделать так, чтобы сумму статистики, которую присваиваю к **sum_fanfik** далее в **where** можно было добавить в условие при выводе, **sum_fanfik >= 1**. Записывая именно так, происходит какая то ошибка, не понимаю в чем дело... Подскажи пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Алиас не виден в предложении where, поэтому придется повторить всю конструкцию.

Comment: @msi не понял, но ведь в ORDER BY работает, а в WHERE нет, можете показать на примере?

Comment: А Order by выполняется после:
http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_having_clause.html

Comment: @msi Нет, не работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для фильтрации по вычисленным столбцам используется `HAVING`. `WHERE` здесь не применим. `WHERE` применяет условие к строкам таблицы, тогда как `HAVING` применяет условие к строкам результата.

```
$sql_popular = mysql_query("
SELECT `id`,`name`,`view`,`avatar`, 
   ((SELECT SUM((((`like` * 10) + `view`) - (`dizlike` * 10))) 
       FROM `fanfik` 
       WHERE `active`='1' AND `id_users` = `u`.id) + `view`) AS sum_fanfik 
FROM `users` u 
WHERE `activation`='1' AND `date` >= adddate(now(), interval - 30 day) 

HAVING sum_fanfik >= 1 

ORDER BY sum_fanfik DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 20");
```

Почитайте мануал про SELECT. Там же найдете и HAVING и условия его использования: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Comment: Кажется работает, спасибо большое:)